# Site Rss not seen by browser

Tags: rss, encoding

We have a site http://ort.org.il built with WP 3.1.2. Its RSS address should be http://ort.org.il/feed/, but nothing shows up there. I can see the feed in the View Source, but not in the browser, and not in one of our other applications, that reads the RSS from this site.

What could be the problem, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is an invalid UTF-8 character in the excerpt `<description>`. The text is cut off in the middle of a multi-byte character, rendering your complete feed invalid. You get a slightly hint when you look at it in Opera.

Do you filter `'bloginfo_rss'` or `'get_bloginfo_rss'`? Disable all plugins and look if the feed is still broken.

Comment: We disabled all plugins, and discovered that it was the advanced_excerpt plugin that broke the RSS. Since we can do without that plugin, we left it turned off and now the RSS renders beautifully! thank you!

Comment: @LeaCohen Tell the author of the plugin to use my function [`utf8_truncate()`](https://gist.github.com/864355). It prevents broken characters.